# My obb file is getting removed from device automatically (android expansion files)

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am trying to test my expansion file for my application. I manually place my main.version.pkg.obb file in Android/obb/pkg/ folder in my Galaxy S3 phone. But the device is automatically removing my file everytime. Can someone tell me why is this happening.

I am just copying the file using usb and the moment I remove usb and connect again, the file is getting removed (which shows scanner is removing my obb file).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Kit Kat 4.4.2.
If that's the case,then this is due to a bug in kitkat that many people are facing.Google has kept this bug in mind and is working on it.It will be solved with the next kit kat update.

Comment: The issue was coz of another reason which got resolved. I was not working on Kitkat then.. It was Jellybean and below. But thanks for the update. i will check it for Kitkat..